# If $\sin x + \cos x +\tan x + \cot x +\sec x +\csc x=7$, then $\sin 2x$ is a root of $x^2 -44x + 36$ .

Tags: trigonometry

> If
>   $$\sin x + \cos x +\tan x + \cot x +\sec x +\csc x=7$$
>   then show that $\sin(2x)$ is a root of the equation $x^2 -44x + 36$.

How do I solve this question?

Comment: That is 44 and 36. not 44^x or 3^6.

Comment: By cosecx do you mean the function $\csc x=\frac{1}{\sin x}$?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1816715/409 . In fact, [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1817049/409) solves your problem as a prelude to answering that question.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1816715/find-k-if-sum-of-all-trigonometric-ratios-is-7